# Loud High-Pitched brake squeal

Tags: toyota, brakes, corolla

I have a 2005 Toyota Corolla with squeaking from brakes.

Details:
Very High Pitched
Worse when wet / rainy
Only happens within certain peddle range (stops if I press soft or real hard)
Steadily goes away while driving (but restarts after parking for a while)

Solutions:
Pads are good, they have over half the pad left
I tried the anti-break squeal stuff on the back of the pad, no help at all

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried:

- Anti-squeal spray (worthless)
- Sanding pads
- Sanding rotors

No luck

I eventually changed the (apparently) good pads, and the squealing went away. Even though they had plenty of pad left, I think they were the original pads on the car making them about 12 years old (I got the car with only 31K miles). Maybe that was it?

Answer (score 1):

You could have whats called "glazing", thats what my techs refer to it as. Thats when your rotors get warm/hot and create a very smooth surface like a mirror. You want friction against friction for your brakes. If you can see your reflection in the rotor (glass like surface), Id suggest having the brake rotors resurfaced. Ask a friend to stand outside of the vehicle while you brake to verify the position of the squeaking noise, from the echo in the cabin self diagnostic can be tricky for brake squeak.

Comment: I'll take a look this weekend.